# Company is requesting W-9 before refunding purchase

Tags: united-states, taxes, refund, consumer-protection

My significant other purchased a spa day-pass from one of those deal-a-day sites (similar to Groupon, but done locally). The spa wouldn't accept the day-pass, so she's trying to get a refund from the deal-a-day site. They are requesting she fill out a W-9 before they refund any money. Their explanation is their parent company requires a W-9 before cutting any check. This doesn't sound appropriate, especially giving them her SSN for a mere refund.

Two questions -

1. Should a company require a W9 when you haven't done any work for them? I searched their site's terms and conditions and it doesn't list anything about a W9 required for refund.
2. If we do give them a W9, is that automatically going to cause us to report that as earned income in this years taxes?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd call the credit card company and consider it a fraudulent charge, if it simply wasn't honored.

Comment: Didn't think about that. Not sure if it matters, but we've already paid that month's balance off. Worth a phone call, at least.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you've paid that month's balance off, you can still dispute it (I think you can dispute within 60 days of the transaction, check with your credit card service)

Comment: I for one *wouldn't* call the credit card company immediately, unless you're near the end of the window to dispute the charge, or they continue to be recalcitrant. The credit card company resolution process will take a long time. There's a good chance that you'll actually resolve your dispute and then call up the credit card company and say "we resolved the dispute, stop worrying about it." so save yourself the work.

Comment: @fennec Having credit card company sending them a charge-back letter makes wonders to the dispute resolution. They get hefty fines and penalties (including rate increases) based on the amount of charge-backs against them. So once the CC company is involved, they're usually much more willing to resolve the dispute before the CC company makes the decision, than before the CC company involvement.

Comment: I've resolved these kinds of disputes with the CC company with very little hassle in the past.

Comment: Just in passing, that charge is not _fraudulent_ unless they knew, when they billed you, that the pass would not be honored. That doesn't mean that you're not entitled to a refund; you certainly are. But fraud is probably too harsh a word here.

Comment: When I disputed a credit-card charge, the credit card company immediately gave me a credit for the disputed amount, then we started the discussion with the vendor.

Comment: I'm almost a decade late. I did a google search and found this. our company requires w9's and this whole refund w9 issue came up. our problem is that our company is HUGE and has one financial system with 100 users. out of the 100 users, only about 5 have access to sensitive information (ssn's). those ssn's are used as a control in our financial system software, so with that someone can pull up your 'vendor record' without adding you to the system (again) if you're already in there. also, because the SSN is being used as a control in the records that is why we require the w9.

Comment: we're currently looking to create an updated form that doesn't look so official and only for our records.

Answer (score 17):

W9 is required for any payments.

However, in your case - these are not payments, but **refunds**, i.e.: you're not receiving any income from the company that is subject to tax or withholding rules, you're receiving money that is yours already.

I do not think they have a right to demand W9 as a condition of refund, and as Joe suggested - would dispute the charge as fraudulent.

Comment: Also, if you paid with a credit card, they don't have to 'cut you a check'. They just need to refund the charge and any processor will allow them to do that within 90 days.

Answer (score 5):

> [Form W-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_W-9) (officially, the "Request for Taxpayer Identification Number and Certification") is used in the United States income tax system by a third party who must file an information return with the Internal Revenue Service (IRS). It requests the name, address, and taxpayer identification information of a taxpayer (in the form of a Social Security Number or Employer Identification Number).

A W-9 is typically required when an individual is doing work, as a contractor or as an employee, for a company and will be paid more than $600 in a tax-year.  The company is required to file a W-2 or a 1099 and so requests a W-9 to get the information necessary for those forms.

I cannot say if it is incompetence on the part of the accounting department or a deliberate ploy to make the refund process more onerous, but do not comply.  Politely nsist on a refund without any further information.  If the company refuses, request a charge-back from the credit-card company, file a complaint with the consumer-protection department of the state where the company is located, and write a bad review on Yelp or wherever else seems appropriate.

Comment: Employee requires W-4 not W-9. W-9 is used for contractor as you say, and _many_ other 109X-reportable (or 5498) things such as bank, broker and mutual-fund accounts (including IRA HSA 529 etc), real estate sales, home mortgages, college tuition, payment cards and networks (merchant/seller-side), gambling winnings (with some exclusions), lawsuit settlement (some might consider this the same as the previous <G>), etc. But not a refund of a purchase.